# Tensorboard: Change line graph step label

Tags: python, label, tensorflow, linegraph, tensorboard

I was wondering whether there is a way to change the label of "step" on the line graph in tensorboard. 
 For example when I want to plot a learning curve, I need my x-axis label to be the "data size" of my line graph, not "step".

Comment: Seems not possible currently.